# Unit tests failing without any message if linked to a custom framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, swift

**Update (From Build log):**

```
"The bundle “Lib2Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." 

(dlopen_preflight(/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lib2-gaplfrtqethacsgkmjmlivcyuity/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lib2Tests.xctest/Lib2Tests): 

Library not loaded: @rpath/Lib1.framework/Lib1
```

It seems the lib2.framework project only linked the Lib1.framework and it didn't embed it, and there's no option to embed the framework inside another cocoa touch framework, that's why at the end unit test failed as it couldn't find the referenced Lib1.framework.

**put simply if FrameworkB is dependent on FrameworkA for some functionality down the road, UnitTests of FrameworkB will cease to run - if FrameworkA is linked to FrameworkB**

---

**Setup**

I've created a simple isolated case to demonstrate and reproduce the problem.

I've 2 Swift Cocoa Touch Frameworks (`Lib1` & `Lib2` - `Lib2` is dependent on `Lib1` - single swift file with single unit test in each)

`Lib2` unit tests will only work if you remove the linked `Lib1`. Interestingly both projects works on their own if run independently.

**Question:** is this a bug in Xcode? any workarounds?

**Smallest Reproducible Example Project**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kycnvt1qvz8zw4o/LibTest.zip?dl=0

I'm attaching a screenshot, it's weird, no error messages or failure details in the console, all I get is a notification on the side the unit test failed. The test is not complicated, single line instantiating a class and it's runs successfully if I remove the link to my custom framework. (the custom framework itself also simple and runs/tests successfully on it's own) To observer this behavior simply delete the linked framework from the project files and run "Test" again. I believe the error is related to project files settings etc. and the solution requires to look into project file itself.

[image]

Comment: Could you narrow down to the smallest reproducible example?

Comment: yes the dropbox link has the smallest reproducible example, Lib1 has 1 swift file only, same with Lib2. both projects will work fine independently with successful unit tests. but as long as you link the .framework file of lib1 to lib2, the unit test of lib2 fails without a message

Comment: I still think it can be done without a dropbox link. ;)

Comment: how? I didn't get you. well if you are asking me to write code on the question thread, the code is nothing, an empty class file with an init function, and unit test has this line `XCTAssertNotNil(File1(), "File 1 didn't instantiate")` and it works fine, the reason I used dropbox so people can work with the project itself, the problem lies in the project settings that I can't reproduce on the question thread,

Comment: otherwise you can create your own cocoa touch framework files to test it, (don't forget to specify in your lib1 setting that it has swift code in it (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1881/_index.html )

Comment: What does it mean "unit tests failing"? They don't compile? They don't link? Tests suddenly stop passing? It's unclear what you're asking, this question does not fit well into the SO model.

Comment: good question, it compiles fine, link I'm not sure. I've attached a screenshot, that's all I get, nothing in the console. it's a silent failure, that's not making any sense to me. hopefully the test project files will help you to understand. I've mentioned in my question headline that unit test fail without any message